# VBA to allow certain users view & edit certain sheets in a workbook using Login Form & admin sheet with usernames and passwords in tables

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks in advance for any help I may get.

The company I currently work for has had me build a spreadsheet based system to do our New Product Development with costing.  However, many people accessing this workbook are not allowed to view costing per company policy so they have asked to put security on this workbook with a login form. I have built the login form with a username textbox (txtUser) and a password textbox (txtPass) and a command button (cmdLogin).  Within the sheet we have the following sheets. Summary, Quote, Customer Service, Production, Quality, Inventory, Finance, Inventory, Maintenance, Purchasing, Data, Molds, and Admin.   Within The Admin Sheet I have two tables. table 1 (tblUsers) has a list of all the usernames, passwords and the list of sheets they will be allowed to see.  Attached is the document. Upon a user opening the workbook I'd like for my form to pop up and request their username and password.  if the username and password match what I have in tblUser then I want to grant them access to the list of sheets I have given them permission to view in tblUser and hide all the rest. If they didn't put in the correct password then I'd like for them to have a message box that ask them if they'd like to retry or close the program.  if they retry I'd like to display the userform again.  I tried some samples of what was left in some other forums but can't seems to get it to adjust for having a table.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Stackoverflow. You have asked for a few things. I would suggest that you break this down in different posts. But as a overall logic, rather than have a userform to ask the user to login, you can just get the user logged into the PC and have a sheet with username list. Then when a user tries to open the workbook and they exists in your list, you can show them the sheets. If the user doesn't exist in the sheet, you can display a message to contact you to be added to the list or just close the workbook with a message saying you are not authorise to view this workbook

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you hide all the sheets but one on closing the workbook. (You must have one visible so make that a sheet that says "You do not have permission to view this workbook") Then on opening the workbook, pop up your form and selectively unhide the desired sheets.

The longer answer is that no such security system is worth much - anyone could google how to crack it in minutes. But it will make your bosses happy I guess. (If you really want to make it secure you hide the costing data from everyone by doing it in a UDF in a compiled C+ module  and only bringing the results back.)